# Why is there a blank space?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to learn UI design with flutter.

This is main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/HomePage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is HomePage.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                child: Image.asset("ui_images/top_left.png")),
          ),
          
          Text("Welcome to QuizZers"),
          Text("It is a modern quiz game"),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Click to Start Game")),

          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Image.asset("ui_images/bottom_right.png"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code. As you can see I wrote Alingment.bottomRight in my code. But I have space at bottom. I don't want that. What can I do?

[screenshot of the application screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko2LY.png)

Comment: you specified your image height to 200

Comment: Do you have another wrapper for this widget as a parent widget? Look here https://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/podYEKG

Comment: Show your full code implementation. We can't see were the background image is being set or if you're using "cover" or not to scale.

Comment: I guess your image aspect ratio makes it appear like that. Try setting fit property of Image.asset to BoxFit.cover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped your scaffold body with a SafeArea and added appBar, but I don't see any space between image and device. Maybe it's due to a lack of padding which is solved by SafeArea.

```
 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/pic.jpeg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text("Welcome to QuizZers"),
        Text("It is a modern quiz game"),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Click to Start Game")),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/download.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```